# MySQL Slow Group By Query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have 6 tables 
1. Products p 
2. Attributes  a
3. Product and Attribute pa (ID, pID, aID )
4. Company  c
5. USer   u
6. Company and User cu    (ID, cID, uID)

Now in admin i want to see company products and its attributes.

```
SELECT p.ID, p.name
from  products p
LEFT JOIN Product and Attribute pa  ON pa.pID =  p.ID 
LEFT JOIN Attributes a  ON a.pID =  pa.aID
LEFT JOIN Company and User cu  ON cu.UiD  = p.uID    AND cu.cID = 121 (spcific company id) 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Please post your table schematics, too (`DESCRIBE yourtables;`).

Answer (score 0):

In [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html), `GROUP BY` implies `ORDER BY`

If no particular order in needed, add `ORDER BY NULL`

> By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you specified ORDER BY col1, col2, ... in the query as well. If you include an ORDER BY clause explicitly that contains the same column list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the sorting still occurs. If a query includes GROUP BY but you want to avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by specifying ORDER BY NULL. For example: